# Signed wire: synthesize view

Tags: verilog, wire, synthesis

What does this expression mean in Verilog?

```
wire signed [6:0] X [0:0];
```

What would this look like if it was synthesized?

Comment: hmm... I am not sure how to simplify my question. I am just curious what this would look like if it was synthesized. Is this 6 parallel wires? Or a wire X[0] that has a 7-bit value on it?

Comment: It's *wires*. That's it. Being signed or unsigned is something that these wires *mean* to the stuff they are connected to.

Comment: I do not have the tools to run a simulation and synthesize at the moment.

Comment: @user367640 You always have [EDA Playground](https://edaplayground.com/)

Comment: If you are asking about the syntax, it is an unpacked vector of one element of packed 7-bit vectors. Will get synthesized into 7 wires, unless optimized out. Why does it have to be a vector of 1 element? I don't know. Maybe it is just a result of some parametrized design were this vector can be configured to be more than one element.

Comment: Thank you @EugeneSh. I was not aware of EDA playground, it looks like a great tool and also thank you for providing an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a declaration, not an expression. A declaration affects how it will be interpreted within an expression. And without use in an expression, the declaration *disappears* in synthesis.

Regarding the `[0:0]`, the SystemVerilog LRM is unclear on how it is to be interpreted, but most tools treat an array with only on element equivalent to single vector.

wire signed [6:0] X;

The *signedness* of the vector only affects expression that need sign extension or relational operators.